# d3.event.x does not get the x cursor's position

Tags: d3.js

I do not understand why d3.event.x == NaN and not the x cursor's position when I use d3.behavior.drag().
I used d3.event.sourceEvent.offsetX instead, but it works only with Chrome (e.g. not with Firefox).
The side effect can be seen here :
http://gloumouth1.free.fr/test/Nature
The user can move the "frequency cursors" only with Chrome.
Any idea ?
G.

Answer (score 14):

From my point of view, d3.js is terrible documented library. Sorry [Mike Bostock](https://github.com/mbostock), but personally for me it's sometimes absolutely impossible to find "why", without debugging the source and examples.

Now, the answer:

**THE FIRST**

d3 can create and recognize own events like d3.event.x properly in any browser, **BUT** you should draw draggable interface elements **INSIDE** `<g></g>`! You should not place circles, rectangles or whatever you going to drag later precisely in `<svg></svg>`. This is not documented.

Example:

```
<svg>
   <rect></rect>  // you can not use 'd3.event.x' or 'd3.event.y' for this element.
                  // for this element is possible to use 'd3.event.sourceEvent.x' in Chrome 
                  // and 'd3.event.sourceEvent.offsetX' in Firefox.
                  // d3.event.x === NaN, d3.event.y === NaN in any browser
   <g>
      <rect></rect> //  'd3.event.x' and 'd3.event.y' will work for this element
   </g>
<svg>
```

**THE SECOND**

The `<g></g>` wrapper should store the `data([{x:..., y:...}])` even you not need it. Without the data in `<g></g>`, the `.origin()` method will not work properly and element will jump unpredictably under cursor over the window.

**FINALLY**

Lets combine all knowledge about dragging in one example:

```
    var draggable = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(Object) // the sequence function(d){return(d);} in not necessary 
            .on("drag", drg);

    var board = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr({width: 500, height: 500});
    var wrap = board.append("svg:g")
            .data([{x: 100, y: 100}]); // this is the coordinates of draggable element
                                       // they should be stored in <g></g> wrapper as the data

// IMPORTANT! There is no wrap.data().enter() sequence
// You should not call .enter() method for <g></g> data,
// but nested elements will read the data() freely 

    var handle = wrap.append("svg:circle")
            .attr({
                cx: function(d){return(d.x);}, // position of circle will be stored in the data property of <g> element
                cy: function(d){return(d.x);}, 
                r: 30, 
                fill: "gray", 
                stroke: "black"
            }).call(draggable);

    function drg(d){
        // now d3.event returns not a mouse event, 
        // but Object {type: "drag", x: ..., y: ..., dx: ..., dy: ...}
        d3.select(this).attr({
            // reposition the circle and
            // update of d.x, d.y
            cx: d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(500 - 60, d3.event.x)), // 500 - width of svg, 60 - width of circle  
            cy: d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(500 - 60, d3.event.y))  // 500 - height of svg, 60 - height of circle
        });        
    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/c8e2Lj9d/4/

Comment: I'm not sure if misunderstood a point you were making, but I changed your code to remove the <g> element and it seems to work just fine?  http://jsfiddle.net/c8e2Lj9d/6/

Comment: it is indeed a horribly documented library, upvote for that